# How to return data through intents

Tags: android, android-intent

I know I can send data to other activities using `putExtra()`.
In this case, the receiving intent has to manage the data. Is there a way to send data to another intent and the data is being returned when the intent finishes in `onActivityResult()`?

What I want to do:

1. search for a contact using user input as name
2. if nothing is found, start contact picker intent
3. when contact picker returns the contact the user picked, still be
   able to know the initial input the user made

So I thought about sending the user input to the contact picker intent and making it return this data too.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, look at `startActivityForResult` and  `onActivityResult`, where you pass an identifier to `startActivityForResult` that identifies the sender e.g.:

```
intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                    startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
                    break;
```

When the targeted intent has finished the system calls `onActivityResult`

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    // code 1 = take picture
    if(requestCode==1  && resultCode==RESULT_OK) {
```

here the '1' from startAct.. is passed in as `requestCode` parameter and the results in 'data'. What is actually sent depends on the activity you call.

E.g. in your own code you could do the following in the called Intent to e.g. return the string "Hello World" to the caller ("data" is the key later):

```
  Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.putExtra("data", "Hello World");
    setResult(RESULT_OK,intent);
```

And then retrieve it via `data.get("data")`

For some more examples have a look at [this class for the first part](https://github.com/pilhuhn/ZwitscherA/blob/master/src/de/bsd/zwitscher/NewTweetActivity.java) (lines 373+) and [this one for an own intent that returns data](https://github.com/pilhuhn/ZwitscherA/blob/master/src/de/bsd/zwitscher/MultiSelectListActivity.java).

Comment: That's what I am doing to receive the contact the user picked ;-) But there's no sign that any of my extra data will be returned.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. "What is actually sent depends on the activity you call." So, despite the requestCode, which is always the same, I cannot send and receive custom data, like user input?

Comment: The user input you return from the called intent is the "Hello World" in my last example

Comment: you misunderstand me ;-) The intent I am calling is not one of mine, e.g. the android contact list. So I cannot control what the intent is returning. I was wondering if there is a generic way to send data to an intent which will be returned for sure.

Comment: You mean like an "echo service" You could code one up. The android docs do have a list of "official" intents. And then there is the openintents project listing more intents that are in common usage.